# "life" vs. "the life"

Tags: articles

my first question here. 
"The life seems to work for them": why did the author of this phrase use "the" before "life"? Does it have to do with meaning, vernacular or what else?
Thanks

Comment: We need context to answer! The author is probably talking about a specific career or some other specific way of life that has already been mentioned before in this piece of writing. He uses *"the"* because he's not talking about life in general.

Comment: This question is better off on [ell.se]

Comment: "The life" roughly equates to "lifestyle" -- the conditions in which the individual lives and works.  "The life" referred to might be one of partying 24/7, it might be one of working 24/7 on computer geek stuff, or it might be one of living rustically in a one-room log cabin with no running water.

Comment: The context is people living in a rundown farmhouse, though "the life seems...". Thanks Hot Licks and Colin Fine for clarifying this.

Answer (score 3):

The two sentences

> Life seems to work for them.

and

> The life seems to work for them.

have different meanings (though they might be used in the same circumstances).

The first is general: how they live is successful.

The second is focusing on their particular life: probably the way they have chosen to live. It means something like "The life that they have chosen (or found, or been lucky enough to have) seems to work for them".

Comment: +1. As in "He works on a merchant sea vessel. The life seems to suit him."

Comment: I disagree on your reading of the first sentence. Without a definite article before it, "life" would have to mean 'living in general'/'being alive'. It's like saying "Food is good" vs. "The food you cook is good." Well, yeah. Food is good. Eating food keeps you from dying. But the food you cook is high quality food, very nutritious and super tasty!

Comment: @miltonaut: Yes, but. Generally I agree with you, but in a case like this I don't see how it can have that meaning: I take it as "life in general _as experienced by them_ seems to work for them", which is not too different from what I said.

Comment: Okay, I'll take back my downvote. Your response reminded me of the colloquialism "life is good"in which 'life' has the "life in general as experienced by them" meaning. I still don't like the sentence "Life seems to work for them," though. It might technically be grammatical, but it feels forced and unnatural.

Comment: @Miltonaut: I agree that it doesn't read well.